# Mongoose populate() method throwing 'execPopulate is not a function' error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm facing an issue with the Mongoose library in my Node.js project. I have a schema with a **`populate()`** method, and when I attempt to use it, I encounter the following error:

```
Error creating Annonce: TypeError: this.populate(...).execPopulate is not a function
[1]     at model.<anonymous> (file:///C:/MyApp/Front-end/backend/models/annonceModel.js:65:38)
[1]     at callMiddlewareFunction (C:\MyApp\Front-end\backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:628:27)
[1]     at model.next (C:\MyApp\Front-end\backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:93:7)
[1]     at _next (C:\MyApp\Front-end\backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:146:10)
[1]     at C:\MyApp\Front-end\backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:653:30
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

**Versions:**

- Node.js: 14.17.0
- Mongoose: 7.4.2

Here is the Schema where I'm getting the bug

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const annonceSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    tele: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    paragraph: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    selectedCity: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    selectedJob: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    selectedPlace: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    category: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    announcementType: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    createdBy: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    annonceUserStore: {
      type: Boolean, 
    },
    validated: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },

  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

annonceSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  try {
    if (!this.createdBy) {
      return next();
    }

    await this.populate("createdBy").execPopulate();

    const populatedCreatedBy = this.createdBy;

    this.annonceUserStore = populatedCreatedBy.userHasStore;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

const Annonce = mongoose.model("Annonce", annonceSchema);
export default Annonce;
```

I've verified that the **`User`** model is correctly defined and exported.:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    tele: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    job: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    userHasStore: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false, 
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});
userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
};

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

export default User;
I've attempted to update Mongoose to the latest version.
```

and I'm using the latest version of mongoose

Comment: Where did you get that code from? What have you researched? Is [this note about removal in the 6.0 upgrade documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#removed-execpopulate) relevant?